# Meteor and Iron-Router Subscription Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Member already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

**Important: I'm currently working with Meteor and Iron-Router both in the *SHARK* branch**

To abstract the problem, lets say I have two routes:

```
// Home
this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    action: function() {
        // Performing some animation
    }
});

// User profile
this.route('profile', {
    path: '/profile/:id',
    controller: UserShowRouter
});
```

The UserShowRouter looks something like this:

```
UserShowRouter = RouteController.extend({

before: function() {
    this.subscribe('user', this.params.id).wait();
    this.subscribe('userPlaylists', this.params.id).wait();
},

data: function() {

    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({
            'profile.username': this.params.id
        }),

    var playlistsMade = Playlists.find({
            'user.id': user._id
    });

    return {
        user: user,
        playlistsMade: playlistsMade,
    };

},

action: function() {
    this.render('profile', {
        to: 'rightbarYield'
    });
}
```

});

A `user` has several `playlists`. On the user's profile page the user data and the playlists he owns should be shown.

In the before hook I subscribe to the user and to all playlists the user owns. Here are the according publish functions:

```
Meteor.publish('user', function(username) {
    return Meteor.users.find({
        'profile.username': username
     });
});

Meteor.publish('userPlaylists', function(username) {
    return Playlists.find({
        'user.username': username
    });
});
```

**Following problem occurs:** When I visit the `/profile/user` page for the first time everything works like a charm. When I change from the `/profile/user` page to the `/` (home) page and then back to the `/profile/user` following exception gets thrown:

```
Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Member already exists: jzJMYRTYjG9FDqHmT
  at _extend.add (http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b7accb7b6966f638ff085b5d7f310d129aad8c19:1757:17)
  at Object.ObserveSequence.observe.addedAt (http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b7accb7b6966f638ff085b5d7f310d129aad8c19:3572:15)
  at Object.diffFn.addedBefore (http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?c4bfebff26188a6d7bd7b902bf9ad3e3c87a0f77:196:17)
  at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?56dbd9be5b85de2aee072a05810b82c155a20d99:2649:42
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?13ab483e8a3c795d9991577e65e811cd0b827997:130:11)
  at LocalCollection._diffQueryOrderedChanges (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?56dbd9be5b85de2aee072a05810b82c155a20d99:2639:5)
  at diffArray (http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?c4bfebff26188a6d7bd7b902bf9ad3e3c87a0f77:194:3)
  at http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?c4bfebff26188a6d7bd7b902bf9ad3e3c87a0f77:125:11
  at Object._.extend.nonreactive (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?34f4906d0a01d1c2873bed712b3bd039da3c9bab:341:14)
```

This problem **does not occur** when I subscribe to all playlists **at the beginning** in my `main.js` (not in the routeController) `Meteor.subscribe('playlists')`

But this brings along following issue: When I'm not at the `profile/user` route anymore, but at at the home router `/` and the data of one of the existing playlists changes (e.g. the title is changed) and the dependency gets recomputed following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
  at Object.ObserveSequence.observe.changed (http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?b7accb7b6966f638ff085b5d7f310d129aad8c19:3584:52)
  at Object.cursor.observe.changed (http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?c4bfebff26188a6d7bd7b902bf9ad3e3c87a0f77:137:25)
  at Object.cursor.observeChanges.changed (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?56dbd9be5b85de2aee072a05810b82c155a20d99:1096:19)
  at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?56dbd9be5b85de2aee072a05810b82c155a20d99:349:15
  at _.extend.runTask (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?e2f7aa115469a020bb2030038d4f74b320dc9533:558:11)
  at _.extend.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?e2f7aa115469a020bb2030038d4f74b320dc9533:586:10)
  at _.extend.drain (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?e2f7aa115469a020bb2030038d4f74b320dc9533:594:12)
  at LocalCollection.update (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?56dbd9be5b85de2aee072a05810b82c155a20d99:638:22)
  at Object.self._connection.registerStore.update (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata.js?2f66d8591aa3225badaf5a98bfba28287bff3a3d:239:30)
  at Object.store.(anonymous function) [as update] (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?dab0057c9e7c90bcd874be39d89b9cd54637979b:3583:48)
```

I don't know where the problem lies – with Meteor? with Iron-Router? with my subscriptions or routes? **Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks**

Comment: Looks like a problem within the `shark` branch. This is development code so don't expect it to work ;) Have you tried switching to some other - stable - branch?